# Como obter o exit code de um bloco de comando

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Suponhamos que eu tenha os seguintes comandos em um script

```
susd
systemctl status firewalld
```

Se eu olhar o `exit code` através do echo `$?` ele retorna 0 porque o ultimo comando foi executado com sucesso, mas como eu posso obter o `exit code` de todo o bloco? nesse meu exemplo deveria ser um exit code 1 ou maior pois `susd` não existe.

Comment: Você pode fazer uma verificação pra cada comando, já que o `$?` captura o erro do último comando executado, seria viável pro seu caso?

Comment: Você pode colocar seu código numa função e usar o `$?` para obter o `exit code` da mesma

Answer (score 0):

```
set -e
```

Força a finalização da execução de um pipeline(ou sequência de comandos) ao ocorrer algum erro, assim você consegue pegar o exit status através do $?

Referência: [set](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente não é a melhor opção, mas você pode criar uma função com o `$?` e chamar após cada comando para checar o `exit_code`, algo como:

```
#!/bin/bash

captura_erro(){
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Sucesso"
        else
                echo "Erro"
        fi
}

susd > /dev/null 2>&1
captura_erro
ls > /dev/null 2>&1
captura_erro
catinho > /dev/null 2>&1
captura_erro
```